# what are all the uml data types including primitive types

Tags: uml

This is a list of the data types for uml primitive types. What are all the uml data types? It doesn't have to be primitive types.

```
Boolean
Integer
UnlimitedNatural
String
Real
```

Comment: The DataType instances in UML are only what were needed for the UML spec itself. You can create as many instances of UML DataType as you find useful.

Comment: Isabella, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please check the best answer with the checkmark, if your are satisfied. This will award some points to the answerer.

Answer (score 2):

On p. 69 of UML 2.5 you will find

[image]

These literals have been defined to satisfy definitions used in the UML meta model itself (the section on this details these literals). You are free to add whatever you need on your own.

Datatypes are defined on p. 165:

[image]

UML makes use of `PrimitiveType` (any kind of formula) and `Enumeration` (like shown in www.admiraalit.nl's answer). However, to make a list of *all*  of them would be exhaustive and pointless, I guess. Rather you would define your own `DataType`s to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

UML is a language to define your own classes, data types etc. Yes, UML defines some classes and data types itself, but only those needed to define UML.

The notion of DataType is defined in section 10.2 of the UML 2.5 specification. The primitive types you have mentioned are indeed data types defined by UML (in chapter 21). In addition, UML defines a number of enumerations. Primitive types and enumerations are both special kinds of data types. One example of an enumeration defined in UML is VisibilityKind (section 7.8.24).

[image]

UML does not define general purpose data types like Date other than the primitive types you have mentioned. If you want to use Date as a data type, you can define it in your model, or re-use an exisiting profile. Some teams using UML have a convention that standard data types from a particular programming language or database system can be used as data types in UML.